# Is there a way to display data with foreign key related to the primary key of another table?

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-3

I am making a quiz app backend module. I am trying to edit question and answers, how can I edit Questions and the answers of that related question will show?

I have two tables `questions` and `answers` table.

Question table structure

`id` | `question`

Answers table structure

`id` | `answer` | `question_id`

So `question` table must be connected to `question_id` to fetched it answers.

Right now I have this bug, where if I click any Questions I want to edit shows all the answers even that particular answer is not related to the question.

[Bug or Problem of the app, please see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfnZX.png)

This Controller will call the model

```
public function editPost(){
    $result = $this->post_model->showEditPost();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

This Model queries it to show data.

```
public function showEditPost(){
    // Show answers
    $id = $this->input->get('id');

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('answers');
    $this->db->join('questions', 'answers.question_id = questions.id');
    $this->db->where('questions.id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Show Edit Post function ajax script - this script shows the modal data

```
function showEditPost(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>posts/editPost',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;

        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                html +='<input type="text" value="'+data[i].answer+'" class="form-control" /><hr>';
                }

                $('#showEdit').html(html);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Could not get Data from Database');
            }
        });
}
```

This code triggers the Ajax

```
<div class="modal fade-scale" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Update Answers</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">         
                <form id="myForm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control" />
                    <div id="showEdit"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
         <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
       </div>
     </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div>
```

To display modal

```
//edit
$('#showdata').on('click', '.item-edit', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data');

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Edit Question');
        $('#myForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>posts/updatePost');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'get',
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>posts/editPost',
            data: {id: id},
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                //$('input#question').val(data.question);
                $('input#answer').val(data.answer);

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Could not Edit Data');
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Issue in ```where```, It should like   ```$this->db->where('questions.id',$id );```.You mention only field name not where value.

Comment: @HP371 - hello, yes that is my problem can you help me how can I get the value of that id? if I repalced it hard coded 1 then the output is correct. I also tried using hidden input type value of 1 but still not showing any data

Comment: You can pass id in Ajax data, for that follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post/35590754

Comment: @HP371 hello sir, can you refer to my code as well? or post any modification of my code? really trying my best to figure this out still no luck

Comment: There are many solutions available on just search pass edit id in ajax in php or CI.google,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715214/jquery-php-pass-the-value-to-ajax-i-just-need-the-id-to-edit-the-file

Comment: @HP371 - the `$id` is this     $id = $this->input->get('id'); . and I bring the id to the where clause but still cannot fetch any data

Comment: As your comment, I think you are a beginner in CI/AJAX so first read related tutorial it helps you lot.

Comment: @HP371 -i think this is the best tutorial for learning sir. I just need to move on from this problem figuring it out for hours now

Comment: could you paste your html which triggers the ajax call?

Comment: @AnkitSingh - yes please see above at the very bottom i edited it, that ajax triggers the modal to open and data should be fetched and display

Comment: @AnkitSingh - have you seen the edited code? at the very bottom?

Comment: I deleted my answer as it is not anymore related to the evolution of your question.

Comment: Yes I can see now but it's not that what i want to see. Can you please provide your full source of html to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @AnkitSingh Hello, here it is, my full source code. [Full Source Code](https://pastebin.com/Xn83w12Z)

Comment: @AnkitSingh  - let me know more sir if what more i can help for you to undestand it. thanks!!

Comment: Where is `editPost()`? which calls the model `showEditPost()` method.

Comment: @AnkitSingh yes sir, that is the controller it's this  `public function editPost(){
  $result = $this->post_model->showEditPost();
  echo json_encode($result);
 }`  then it will call the model `showEditPost()` sorry for not bringin it up, i was too frustrated about the problem

Comment: @AnkitSingh - I edited it above also if you may want to see it. thank you!

Comment: Please stop reposting the same question & please fix the problems you have repeatedly been told about. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60678873/3404097 https://stackoverflow.com/q/60679275/3404097 [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace these 2 javascript functions, type parameter should be `get` or `post` in your `$.ajax({type:method_here})`

add the following to your ajax `success:function()`

```
var html = '';
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    html +='<input type="text" value="'+data[i].answer+'" class="form-control" /><hr>';
}
$('#showEdit').html(html);
```

**1. Function ShowAllQuestions**

```
function showAllQuestions(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>posts/showPosts',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            var n=1;

            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                html +='<div class="card">'+
                    '<div class="card-header" style="color:white; background-color:black">'+
                        '<h4>Question</h4>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="card-body">'+
                        '<form>'+
                            '<div class="form-group">'+
                                '<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><h5> Question: </h5></label>'+
                                '<textarea class="form-control" name="question" id="question" rows="8">'+data[i].question+'</textarea>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<hr>'+
                            '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data-id="'+data[i].id+'">Edit </a>&nbsp;'+
                        '</form>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div><br>';
            }

            $('#showdata').html(html);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Could not get Data from Database');
        }
    });
}
```

**2. Function for show answers of particular question**

Send the id of question to the `controller` to get the relevant answers from database. You don't need to send id through `data` parameter when you using codeigniter. It allows you to pass parameters as url segments.

`$this->uri->segment(number_here)` can help you to achive this.
number_here will be replacing with actual number of segment you want to get.

you can learn more about `uri->segment` from [HERE](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

```
//edit
$('#showdata').on('click', '.item-edit', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').text('Edit Question');
    $('#myForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>posts/updatePost');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>posts/editPost/' + id,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var html = '';
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                html +='<input type="text" value="'+data[i].answer+'" class="form-control" /><hr>';
            }
            $('#showEdit').html(html);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Could not Edit Data');
        }
    });
});
```

Get the id inside your controller not in your model

```
public function editPost(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3) //if you don't know about uri->segment learn from user_guide
    $result = $this->post_model->showEditPost($id);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Your model should be

```
public function showEditPost($id){
    // Show answers
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('answers');
    $this->db->join('questions', 'answers.question_id = questions.id');
    $this->db->where('questions.id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: did it work on your end sir? Still did not display data on my end. Thank you for your response

Comment: will I not change the script  function `showEditPost()` ?

Comment: you can use them, I just modified the relavent code.

Comment: thank you, so is there any possibility I can display the data of the answers?  still not getting it though.

Comment: check the console for output. what you getting?

Comment: - okay sir so I am getting this on console `0: {id: "1", answer: "Sydney", question_id: "1", correct: "0", type_id: "0", …}
1: {id: "1", answer: "Melbourne", question_id: "1", correct: "0", type_id: "0", …}
2: {id: "1", answer: "Canberra", question_id: "1", correct: "1", type_id: "0", …}
3: {id: "1", answer: "Brisbane", question_id: "1", correct: "0", type_id: "0", …}` but i cannot fetched it on the modal. It is also dynamic if I click on the other question it is correctly fetched. but it does not show on modal input texts

Comment: do you have solution for that sir? the input text is not display and data are not showing

Comment: I think your data is being displayed, but you can't see because you have a `<input type="hidden" id="answer" >` field in your html code where you are trying to add your output. replace `hidden` type with `text`.

Comment: I've already change it though. I cannot display  the array on the modal. that is the last problem i have. kindly help with the last sir. thank you

Comment: check the updated answer and remove the script function `showEditPost()`

Comment: Thank you!!. please kindly summarize what you've done. please sir I just need to learn from your modifications.

Comment: what are my wrong-doings of my code?

Comment: check the updated answer for brief.